Use similar np.where function in custom Keras loss function
I'm trying to create a custom loss function that calculates the total amount won based on the predictions, actual outcome of games and the odds for the home team to win.
Currently, I've gotten so far as this:
    # Custom loss function to minimize money lost
def custom_loss(odds):
    def loss_func(y_true, y_pred):
        bet_amount = 100  # Constant bet amount (100 euros per game)

        # Money lost or gained calculation
        # If home team won (y_true == 1) and the prediction was correct
        money_lost = tf.where(
            y_true == 1,  # If home team won
            (1 - y_pred) * (odds - 1) * bet_amount,  # Profit (if correct prediction)
            y_pred * bet_amount  # Full loss (if wrong prediction)
        )

        # Return the average loss
        return tf.reduce_mean(money_lost)
    return loss_func

def build_model(input_shape_features):
    # Input for game features
    input_features = Input(shape=input_shape_features, name="game_features")
    
    # Input for odds
    input_odds = Input(shape=(1,), name="odds")

    # Neural network to process game features
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(input_features)
    x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
    output_prob = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)  # Output: probability of home team win
    
    # Add a Lambda layer to pass the odds into the custom loss function
    model = Model(inputs=[input_features, input_odds], outputs=output_prob)

    # Compile the model using a custom loss function
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss(odds=input_odds))

    return model

# Train the model with two inputs
def train_model(X_train_features, X_train_odds, y_train):
    # Build the model
    model = build_model(input_shape_features=(X_train_features.shape[1],))
    
    # Train the model
    model.fit([X_train_features, X_train_odds], y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
    
    return model

But, if I fit this model, I get the following error:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[66], line 1
----> 1 model = train_model(X_train_features, X_train_odds, y_train)

Cell In[64], line 44
     41 model = build_model(input_shape_features=(X_train_features.shape[1],))
     43 # Train the model
---> 44 model.fit([X_train_features, X_train_odds], y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
     46 return model

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

Cell In[64], line 8
      4 bet_amount = 100  # Constant bet amount (100 euros per game)
      6 # Money lost or gained calculation
      7 # If home team won (y_true == 1) and the prediction was correct
----> 8 money_lost = tf.where(
      9     y_true == 1,  # If home team won
     10     (1 - y_pred) * (odds - 1) * bet_amount,  # Profit (if correct prediction)
     11     y_pred * bet_amount  # Full loss (if wrong prediction)
     12 )
     14 # Return the average loss
     15 return tf.reduce_mean(money_lost)

ValueError: Tried to convert 't' to a tensor and failed. Error: A KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function. A KerasTensor is a symbolic placeholder for a shape and dtype, used when constructing Keras Functional models or Keras Functions. You can only use it as input to a Keras layer or a Keras operation (from the namespaces `keras.layers` and `keras.operations`). You are likely doing something like:

```
x = Input(...)
...
tf_fn(x)  # Invalid.
```

What you should do instead is wrap `tf_fn` in a layer:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):
    def call(self, x):
        return tf_fn(x)

x = MyLayer()(x)
```

If I understand correctly, it's not possible to use tf.where() in the way that I use it right now. But I'm still a bit lost how I can achieve this. Basically, I want to sum all the money won if the prediction is correct and all the losses (-100) if the predictions is incorrect.
Any tips are welcome!

EDIT:
I got this code to work, but unfortunately this does not include the odds in the custom loss function. Any idea how I can add this in?
    # Neural network architecture
def build_model(input_shape):
    model = Sequential([
        layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  # Single output: probability of home team winning
    ])
    return model

# Custom loss function
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    bet_amount = 100  # Constant bet amount of 100 euros
    
    # In this case, `y_pred` is the predicted probability of the home team winning
    # You lose the bet amount if the home team loses
    # If the home team wins, you gain the bet amount * (odds - 1)
    # Assuming y_pred represents the predicted probability and odds influence the decision to bet

    # y_pred will be the predicted probability of winning
    money_lost = bet_amount * tf.where(
        y_true == 1,  # Home team wins
        (1 - y_pred),  # If predicted probability was wrong, you lose part of the potential gains
        y_pred  # If home team loses, you lose the entire bet
    )
    
    # The total loss is the mean of the money lost
    return tf.reduce_mean(money_lost)

# Compile the model with the custom loss
def compile_model(model):
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=custom_loss,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

# Example of training the model
def train_model(X_train, y_train):
    model = build_model(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
    compile_model(model)
    
    # Train the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=250, batch_size=32)
    
    return model


The error you're facing is described in the Keras 3 documentation: Calling TF ops with a KerasTensor:

Using a TF op on a Keras tensor during functional model construction is disallowed: "A KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function".
The following snippet of code will reproduce the error:
input = keras.layers.Input([2, 2, 1]) 
tf.squeeze(input)

How to fix it: use an equivalent op from keras.ops.
 input = keras.layers.Input([2, 2, 1]) 
 keras.ops.squeeze(input)


In your case, you should be able to transparently use keras.ops.where instead of tf.where, and, similarly, keras.ops.mean instead of tf.reduce_mean.

Thank you, but I still get a similar error:
ValueError: A KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function. A KerasTensor is a symbolic placeholder for a shape and dtype, used when constructing Keras Functional models or Keras Functions. You can only use it as input to a Keras layer or a Keras operation (from the namespaces keras.layers and keras.operations). You are likely doing something like:
x = Input(...)
...
tf_fn(x)  # Invalid.

